# Maven archetype from project - how to preserve package names?

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-archetype

I'm trying to grab my project and generate an Archetype from it via :

```
archetype:create-from-project
```

The thing is, that my project has src/main/java package structure com.sample.app, but the archetype must have it as user wants when generating the project from archetype, but that is impossible I suppose. It doesn't seem to grab groupId and artifactId and generate  `archetype-resources/src/main/java` based on this input.

Anyway, that's why there is this argument I suppose : packageName

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -DpackageName=com.sample.app
```

But it doesn't work and there is still `archetype-resources/src/main/java/org/sample/app` ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `create-from-project` goal usually automatically detects the base package name and replaced it, so you would end up with having
`\templateproject\target\generated-sources\archetype\src\main\resources\archetype-resources\src\test\java\Foo.java` with a package declaration of `${package}`

Try the archetype plugin and create-from-project with a nearly empty hello-world project and you will see that the generated archetype has the package removed. That way, the user who uses `archetype:generate` can specify his package name at generation time.

Comment: that what happened with the first version of archetype-plugin I used, it extracted the package structure, I was telling myself, cool now when I generate it as a user and input groupId and artifactId it will generate the base package structure...but nothing happened... then I used the most fresh plugin and it didn't even removed the base package structure when creating archetype from project... It's kind of in development, this is in source code of the Mojo : private String packageName;//Find a better way to resolve the package!!! enforce usage of the configurator

Comment: oh so it depends on the Maven Plugin version. which one are you using?

Comment: First off, the default one, that is served when you don't specify version, then 2.0-alpha-6-SNAPSHOT ... Finally I made it work with 2.0-alpha-4 ... but the sad point is that  I don't know what was the reason :-) But many thanks mhaller, you pointed me the right direction

Comment: btw it changes only "package" declarations at the top of class...it doesn't change imports package names...I'm going crazy form this plugin already

Comment: create-from-project is meant as a convenience to quickly create new simple archetypes. Usually, you hand-craft archetypes so you have full control over everything.